# Integration with a Fourier transform

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Consider a function $f$ that has smooth Fourier transform $\widehat{f}$ with compact support. In  a particular problem I am considering, it would be useful to be able to compute the integral

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \widehat{f}(u) \ \frac{(e^{h-2\pi i u}-1)}{h-2\pi i u} \ du$$

where $h >0$. Is anything known about this integral? In particular can we compute this integral for general $f$ as above?

Any help/ideas/comments will be appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Possibly you already know that the second factor in the integral is close to being "sinc" evaluated at $h-2\pi iu$, where $\hbox{sinc(x)}={\sin x\over x}$? ... and that since is a Fourier transform of an interval... That stuff?

Comment: ie. $\langle \hat{f},\hat{g}\rangle=\langle f,g\rangle$ where $\hat{g}=(e^{h-2\pi iu}-1)/(h+2\pi iu)$

Comment: Thanks both for the comments. Reuns, do we know what $g$ is? Paul, does the observation using $sinc(x)$ allow us to rewrite the integral?

Answer (score 1):

$$
      \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\widehat{f}(u)\left.\frac{e^{t(h-2\pi iu)}}{h-2\pi iu}\right|_{t=0}^{1}du \\
      = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\widehat{f}(u)\int_0^1e^{t(h-2\pi iu)}dt du \\
      = \int_{0}^{1}e^{th}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\widehat{f}(u)e^{-2\pi itu} du dt \\
      = \int_{0}^{1}e^{th}f(-t)dt
$$